# jquery Chosen onchange event lost after updating

Tags: jquery

I have a chosen multiselect which gets updated with new values based on another multiselect.  There is an onchange event on the other select which updates the chosen; the new values and everything come in via AJAX.

Now, after updating the chosen, it loses the onChange event.

I have tried to then add it back after the update, but that doesn't work.

```
$('#Metrics').trigger("chosen:updated");
$('#Metrics').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    graphit();
});
```

I have also tried at the instantiation

```
$('#Metrics').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    graphit();
});

$('Metrics').on('chosen:updated', function(evt, params) {
    graphit();
});
```

But this doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

So you can scope your event trigger higher than the control itself in jQuery. Updating the control then won't destroy the event handler as it's not bound to the control itself. Since you're referencing it by an ID in your example, you won't run the risk of unintentionally binding to other elements within the new scope.

**Example**

```
 $(document.body).on('chosen:updated', '#Metrics', function(evt, params) {
     graphit();
 });
```

[jQuery `.on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the help.  However, this still doesn't work.  Right after updating the Metrics chosen, it stops the onChange functionality that worked prior to that.  The page itself is http://stockfractions.com/indexnew.php

Comment: Hey, I just tested in my Chrome, and your `graphit()` function fires every time I add or delete something in the Metrics box.  What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: Add or remove a company and then go back to the metrics.  And thanks